NextJS & docker & custom-hosting (not vercel): Where is postgressql-connection stored?
I'm dockerizing a nextjs application to host it on a 'custom' cloud provider (not vercel). During development I'm still using the postgresSQL of vercel. The postgresSQL of the new cloud provider is not accessible directly from the internet but only within the intranet. Therefore I need to change the connectionstring during deployment. I found out that the .env file is twice available and I overwrite them both after the nextjs build. But at runtime my app is still using the old connectionstring. But I cannot find its location.
This is the overwrite of the both env-files. The overwrite during docker build is required since nextJS-build requires an existing connection during build.
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.env-hosting ./.next/standalone/.env
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.env-hosting ./.env

Situation is same locally in docker as hosted on the new cloud provider.
I also downloaded the app-directory from the docker image and search for any term of my connectionstring but couldn't find anything.
What do I miss?

The connection string should not be part of the .env file in the image. It should be passed as an environment variable at runtime when the container is started

Is that the same like setting env variable in dockerfile?

The dockerfile ENV command also puts it in the image. I mean https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/container/run/#env or https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/set-environment-variables

I get the docker build running using ARG inside dockerfile (instead of --build-arg cmd-arg). ENV-files are part of dockerignore. I'm setting ENV-variables in k8n yaml file which I can check via pod console. Values are correct. But app is still running against wrong db-host.

Oh you're using kubernetes? You should've mentioned that in your question, especially if that is where you actually want to set the environment variables. I don't have any kubernetes experience though so I can't help there. Maybe try logging process.env in nodejs to see what values are actually arriving for which environment variables.

I missed that. Sorry. Thanks. But I have the same problem locally using docker desktop.
